# Copy columns by its header value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy column from excel "Book1" to another excel "Book2" by determined its cell value.

Let's say the header columns in Book1 are Name, Age, Gender, Address and Group. I want to copy the column "Name", "Age" and "Group" to "Book2". Below coding is what I've done to pull column data by cell coordinate.

Is it possible if I can pull the column from its header value?

```
Sub copyColumns()

    Dim lr As Long, r As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set tgt = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lr = src.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lr

        src.Cells(i, 1).copy
        r = tgt.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        src.Paste Destination:=tgt.Cells(r, 1)

        src.Cells(i, 2).copy
        src.Paste Destination:=tgt.Cells(r, 2)

        src.Cells(i, 5).copy
        src.Paste Destination:=tgt.Cells(r, 3)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to copy the column by column header, you can use this function to get the letter of your header:

```
Function Letter(oSheet As Worksheet, name As String, Optional num As Integer)
If num = 0 Then num = 1
Letter = Application.Match(name, oSheet.Rows(num), 0)
Letter = Split(Cells(, Letter).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Implementation:

```
Sub copycolum()
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2"):

ws.Range(Letter(ws, "Gender") & "2:" & Letter(ws, "Gender") & ws.Range(Letter(ws, "Gender") & "1000000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range(Letter(ws2, "Gender") & "2")

End Sub
```

Note that the function is set to default at row 1, in other words your header is in column 1, if you like you can change this to whatever row your data is in.

Comment: When I tried this, it prompt an error "Type mismatch" on this line "Letter = Split(Cells(, Letter).Address, "$")(1)". Why this happened?

Comment: Did you change "INSERTCOLUMNHEADERHERE", the error usually happens when you do not find the column header.

Comment: I did replace that but just to get clear, there are 4 "INSERTCOLUMNHEADERHERE" fields right that I need to replace. Can you please explain which header need to replace for each field? Let's say header columns are Name, Age, Gender, Address and Group, and I just want to copy only column Name, Age and Group.

Comment: @AjMal I updated it for gender, you still getting the typemismatch error?

Answer (score 0):

There is number of solutions to this problem. For example, declare variables:

```
Dim rw As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim sFields As String
Dim V
Dim j As Integer
```

Chose your column names for copying:

```
sFields = "Name|Age|Group"
V = Split(sFields, "|")
```

And then, inside your For i loop, make two another loops:

```
For Each cl In Intersect(src.Rows(i), src.UsedRange)
    For j = 0 To UBound(V)
        If cl.EntireColumn.Range("A1") = V(j) Then
           tgt.Cells(i, j).Value = src.Cells(i, j).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next cl
```

Intersect(src.Rows(i), src.UsedRange) will chose all cells in row in the range that is actually used (that is, it will not loop through all 16 384 columns. All columns names are in one variable sFields, you can easily modify it. It is string separated with pipes, you will probably never use pipes (|) in your field names, so it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips along the way:

- Always declare every variable you want to use and user Option Explicit at the beginning of your module.
- Dont copy every single cell, copy a range

See the updated code below:

```
Sub copyColumns2()
Dim src As Worksheet, tgt As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, r As Long, I As Long, Col As Long
Dim ColsToCopy, ColToCopy, counter As Integer
ColsToCopy = Array("Name", "Age", "Group")

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set tgt = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
lr = src.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Col = 1 To 20
    For Each ColToCopy In ColsToCopy
        If src.Cells(2, Col).Value = ColToCopy Then
            counter = counter + 1
            src.Range(src.Cells(2, Col), src.Cells(lr, Col)).Copy tgt.Cells(2, counter)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ColToCopy
Next Col

End Sub
```

Comment: I copied the updated code exactly like yours with Option Explicit and attempted to run but it went nothing. Did I miss something?

Comment: It worked perfectly with my testworkbooks. Did you get an error message? Did you put the code in the right workbook and is the first column filled to determine the total rows (you used the same in your code)?

Comment: Maybe your Headers are different (lower/uper case, trailing blanks etc.)? You can enhance the code with changing `If src.Cells(2, Col).Value = ColToCopy Then` to `If trim(lcase(src.Cells(2, Col).Value)) = lcase(ColToCopy) Then`

Comment: In which row are your headers? If they arent in row 2, please change the line `If src.Cells(2, Col).Value = ColToCopy Then`correspondingly.

Comment: My headers are in row 1 for both workbooks. But it still didn't work somehow

Comment: Then change the line `If src.Cells(2, Col).Value = ColToCopy Then` to `If trim(lcase(src.Cells(1, Col).Value)) = lcase(ColToCopy) Then`